# what was the problem with this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35222419/how-to-call-a-static-method-in-same-application-with-different-stack

Is there something wrong in asking how to call a static method on a different stack to be able to use its static fields with new values?

The comments say that ask the library vendor, even if its not a library and I need to know if its possible or not?

Browsing elsewhere I found out that using reflection you can test a singleton method so I wanted to confirm if there is a way to call this static method as well?

Question:

To explain what I actually wanted to ask and understand where was I wrong?

Answer (score 8):

Where to start...

- The question starts with the premise of some third party library being used.  That's fine and all, but *which* third party library were you using?  There are **a lot** of them.
- Two instances of a client to connect to two servers - that sounds like (at least from the description) like you instantiate two clients and point their addresses at different machines.  So, what failed with that?  What did you attempt to do, and why didn't it work?
- **Why are you using reflection??**  Why would that be something that would solve your problem?
- Where is your code?  We don't have inside context into what it is you're asking.  Maybe the issue is with the third party code, maybe it's with yours, but we can't answer for sure until we see some code.

Comment: ok thanks got it, so it seems that I couldnt explain what I am facing. But help me to explain what I wanted to say is that there is a class which has a static method say connect(string ip, int port) then followed by another method send(message). Now I want to connecto to another server with connect(ip2, port2) and then call send

Comment: Explain the problem as if you're trying to explain it to a relative who doesn't know computers.  How would you illustrate what the actual issue is?  How would you articulate what pain points you're going through?  Avoid using as much code jargon as you can, since if you do post your code, we'll be able to determine if the description of your code attempts align with your actual code.

Comment: thanks again, and should I delete this meta post as well? coz this has gotten 2 negative votes as well, sucks up my "small" hard-earned reputation :(

Comment: Votes on Meta don't impact your reputation.